# how to align an 'a' element in html/css

Tags: html, css, alignment, center

I need to align an "a" element in the center

HTML code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cedarville+Cursive' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

    <h1>Olive</h1>
    <a href="page1.html">Enter</a>

</body>
</html>
```

CSS code:

```
body {
background-color: olive;
}

h1 {
font-family: 'Cedarville Cursive', cursive;
font-size: 230px;
text-align: center;
}

a {
font-family: 'Cedarville Cursive', cursive;
color: white;
font-size: 100px;
text-decoration: none;
```

}

I used 'text-align' in 'a' element in the CSS sheet, but it didn't change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`text-align:center;` centers the text inside an element, when you apply it to `<a>`, you are centering the text inside of `<a>` inside of it, but `<a>` is an inline element, it does not stretch, so you need to place it inside a `div`.

```
<div> <a> Ha </a> </div>

div{
text-align:center;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

That's because you can't `text-align` an element that's inline, like `a` is by default. Try this:

```
a {
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    /* ... */
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't convert an inline element to block just to align it.
Use text-align to align the inline children elements (a) and float to align the block children elements (h1)!

Answer (score 1):

You need to use text-align on the **parent (body).** This aligns the inline children.

Answer (score 0):

Because it's an inline element, an  element should always be nested in a block element, regardless of any style questions.

E.g.:

```
<p>
  <a><a href="page1.html">Enter</a>
</p>
```

This way, you can then use something like the following CSS rule:

```
p > a { text-align: center; }
```